# How to fix urlpatternes does not match

Tags: python, django

I am using Django and javascript to create an URL that is entered by a form input but after submitting it I am getting an error that page does not exist even I have the pattern

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('chat',views.index,name='index'),
    path('chat/<str:room_name>',views.room,name='room'), 

]
```

and the javascript code
is

```
document.querySelector('#room-name-submit').onclick = function(e) {
            var roomName = document.querySelector('#room-name-input').value;
            window.location.pathname = '/chat/' + roomName + '/';
        };
```

for example, if we enter lobby my url will be `chat/looby` and it should match with the 'room' , but I am getting error 
Using the URLconf defined in mychat.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

chat [name='index']
chat/ [name='room']
admin/
The current path, chat/lobby/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Did you notice the tiny `/` at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove trailing slash from the url.

Answer (score 0):

for you to be on a safer side, use the named url in your javascript

```
 window.location.pathname = '{% url "room" roomName  %};
```

or add '/' to your url.py

```
 path('chat/<str:room_name>/',views.room,name='room'),
```